# Increment Value $k use Array Insert loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I need to increase the value of the $ k variable every time a record of that loop is inserted in order to insert the array I have with the necessary values. Here I leave a part of the code to see if you can help me.

```php
$k = 0;

foreach ($detalles as $d) {
  $num = $d['stock'];
  $val = floor($num/$limite);

  for($i=0;$i<$limite;$i++) {
    $arr[$i] = $val;
  }
  
  $arr[0] += $num - array_sum($arr);
  
  $this->transac_detail_temp->save([
    'id_trx_header'=> $id,
    'producto' => $d['id_producto'],
    'cantidad' =>  $arr[$k]++,
    'tipo_transaccion'=> 2]
  );
     
}   // foreach detalles
```

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of this code is or what role in all of this `$k` has. You say you need to increase it, so what exactly is preventing you to do so?

Comment: This is a site for programmers. Are you saying that, as a programmer, you don't know how to increment a variable?

Comment: Have you tried using `$k++` where you want to increment the value?

Comment: Hm, you know how to `$arr[$k]++`, do the same for `$k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your question but hope this will be you
Replace this code

```
'cantidad' =>  $arr[$k]++,
```

to

```
'cantidad' =>  $arr[$k],
```

and this code in last section

```
$k++;
```

so final code will be like this

```
$k = 0;

foreach ($detalles as $d) {
 $k++;  //added
 //echo $k."<br>"; // if you want to check update value of $k
 $num = $d['stock'];
 $val = floor($num/$limite);

 for($i=0;$i<$limite;$i++) {
   $arr[$i] = $val;
 }

 $arr[0] += $num - array_sum($arr);

$this->transac_detail_temp->save([
'id_trx_header'=> $id,
'producto' => $d['id_producto'],
'cantidad' =>  $arr[$k], //update 
'tipo_transaccion'=> 2]
 );

}
```

Comment: I have tried with what you tell me, but it always saves me the records with the first element of the array, it does not increase, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. if you want to check increment value then echo this $k value

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro! You saved my life. Very grateful to you.